# Case Statement - Null Values

Tags: vbscript, case, isnull

I am using [Labelview 2015 by Teklynx](https://www.teklynx.com/en/products/label-design-solutions/labelview). It gives the opportunity to place the code in a Visual Basic Scripting tab.

I have some shape and text colors that are driven by `Case` statements. The issue is, I need for the colors to default to "white" or "clear", and remain that way for `Null` values.

Here is the snippet:

```vb
Dim strShapeName
Dim strName
strShapeName = "ShapeLordosis"
strName = "TextLordosis"

If IsNull(Value) Then
    Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).BackColor = vbWhite
    Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).ForeColor = vbWhite
    Document.DocObjects(strName).BackColor = vbWhite
    Document.DocObjects(strName).ForeColor = vbBlack
Else
    Select Case Value
        'BLACK FONT with BRONZE FILL
        Case 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60
            Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).BackColor = RGB(176, 97, 0)
            Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).ForeColor = vbBlack
            Document.DocObjects(strName).BackColor = RGB(176, 97, 0)
            Document.DocObjects(strName).ForeColor = vbBlack
            ...
        'BLACK FONT with SEAFOAM GREEN FILL
        Case 9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69
            Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).BackColor = RGB(45, 208, 0)
            Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).ForeColor = vbBlack
            Document.DocObjects(strName).BackColor = RGB(45, 208, 0)
            Document.DocObjects(strName).ForeColor = vbBlack
        'BLACK FONT with WHITE FILL
        Case Else
            Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).BackColor = vbWhite
            Document.DocObjects(strShapeName).ForeColor = vbBlack
            Document.DocObjects(strName).BackColor = vbWhite
            Document.DocObjects(strName).ForeColor = vbBlack
    End Select
End If
```

Before I added the `If IsNull(Value) Then ...` condition, the code would run. When I added the condition, the code just give an error that a Parameter does not exist. I have seen a suggestion to use `If Else`, but I have not been able to get it to work.

There is an execute button that when I run it, I get the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: '[string: ""]' at "(null)"

In addition, to this tab, there is a checkbox to "Activate Event call". Then there are 3 sub categories that are:

```
Sub OnChangeFieldData(ByVal Variable, ByRef Value, ByRef Valid)

Sub OnBeforeShowFieldDialog(ByVal Variable, ByVal DialogID, ByVal Options, ByVal Parent, ByRef Result)

Sub OnAfterShowFieldDialog(ByVal Variable... etc)
```

Comment: Seems the code does what you need, what is the exact issue?

Comment: Omegastripes, thank you for your reply. Before I added the If Null else, the code would run. I am using this in a label making program, and when I added the If then, the code just give an error that a Parameter does not exist.   It sounds like based on what you are saying, it 'should' be working fine. I am baffled.

Comment: Try to add the line `MsgBox "Test"` or `"WScript.Echo "Test"` somewhere in the beginning of the code, it's necessary to find out at least some method to retrieve values from the script runtime for debug purposes.

Comment: MsgBox "Test" works. WScript does not.   I have learned that I have to create a 'formula' that checks for the null value and will assign a different vaule to throw it into the 'else' case.  I used this       "if(exact({Lordosis1}, ""), "555", {Lordosis1} )"    Also, as I look back at the code I placed above, for some reason all of my objShapeName and objName were changed to strShapeName and strName above.  The final code I have works, but now I am trying to figure out how to revert to a transparent BackColor and ForeColor.  You have been super helpful omegastripes.

Comment: If you changed the code and now you have final working version with only issue to revert to a transparent colors, then edit your question and add update including the new code and exact output description you currently have and you expect. Regarding `strShapeName` and `strName`, I've changed them because `str` prefix is default for strings.

Comment: The final code actually works. The issue was that the code needed to be handled with a formula scenario outside the vbscript itself. Omegatripes has answered my questions properly.